# Define two sequences of i.i.d random variables

Tags: probability, measure-theory, random-variables, borel-cantelli-lemmas

Could you kindly explain in very simple words, or through examples, what these two sequences mean?

$A_n :=\{X_n > X_i, \;for\; i∈\{0,...,n−1\}\},\\
B_n := \{A_n ∩ A_{n+1}\}.$

I just know that $(X_n)_{n∈N}$ is a sequence of i.i.d. random variables with a continuous distribution function and that $n>1$

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: It looks like just a rather sloppy notation for something like "Let $A_n$ be the event that $X_n>X_i$ for $i=0,\dots,n-1$ and let $B_n=A_n\cap A_{n+1}$". But, in all honesty, one can only guess looking at it as written.

Comment: And if I had to compute, for example, $P(A_n)$ how would you do that?

Comment: Depends on $X_i$. If there are no atoms (i.e. the probability that $X_i=X_j$ is $0$ for $i\ne j$), then, by symmetry, $P(A_n)=\frac 1{n+1}$ (among $X_0,\dots, X_n$, each of them has the same chance to be the largest).